# undefined error in less file put under assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, less

I bought a theme from [here](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/lenord-single-page-bootstrap-theme-WB0268292), after I integrated it to my project.
Server raised the error

```
WARN: tilt autoloading 'less' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'less' suggested.
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 262ms

ActionView::Template::Error (.box-shadow is undefined
  (in /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/pixnet_hackathon/website/goood_theme/app/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/less/ace-nav.less)):
    2: %html
    3:   %head
    4:     %title GooodTheme
    5:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    6:     = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    7:     / Description, Keywords and Author
    8:     %meta{content: "Your description", name: "description"}/
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___3827456286267197904_2191503380'
```

The contents in `app/assets/ace-admin-theme/css` [link](https://gist.github.com/poc7667/9949007)

I add two files for including all files under their folder

```
+++ b/app/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/application.css
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+/*
+*= require_tree .
+*/

+++ b/app/assets/ace-admin-theme/js/application.js
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+//= require_tree .
```

Edited two files

```
+++ b/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
@@ -13,5 +13,6 @@
+//= require_tree ../ace-admin-theme/js

+++ b/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
+ *= require_tree ../ace-admin-theme/css
```

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "lenord-single-page-theme")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "ace-admin-theme")
```

The folder structure

```
.
├── avatars
├── css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── ie6
│   ├── img
│   ├── less
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   └── ext
│   └── uncompressed
├── font
├── images
│   └── gallery
├── img
└── js
    ├── date-time
    │   └── locales
    ├── flot
    ├── fuelux
    │   └── data
    ├── jqGrid
    │   └── i18n
    ├── markdown
    ├── uncompressed
    │   ├── date-time
    │   │   └── locales
    │   ├── flot
    │   ├── fuelux
    │   │   └── data
    │   ├── markdown
    │   └── x-editable
    └── x-editable
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1"
gem "therubyracer"
gem "hirb-unicode"
gem "devise"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem "rspec"
gem "awesome_print", require: "ap"
gem "tinymce-rails"
gem "simple_form"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "pg"
gem "taps"
gem "pry"
gem "pry-remote"
gem "pry-nav"
gem "analytics-ruby"
gem "bcrypt-ruby"
gem "bourbon"
gem "cancan"
group :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "guard-rspec"
end

gem "sunspot_rails"
gem "sunspot_solr"
group :assets do
end

gem "simple-navigation"
gem "simple-navigation-bootstrap"

group :assets do
  gem 'less'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to add the `ace-admin-theme` folder to your assets path.

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "ace-admin-theme")
```

Comment: Did you revert your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` changes?  With the assets in the config path you don't want the `require ../` stuff.